# Spring restful services with LDAP authentication

Tags: spring, rest, authentication, ldap

I'm new on Spring framework and I'm trying to create a restful service with LDAP authentication.

For the start, I followed these 2 tutorials on Spring website :
-https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
-https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/

Now I want to create a new service which needs the LDAP authentication but I'm stuck. On the LDAP tutorial it's for a Spring application with user interface.

Me I want to call the service with a username/password or token and then executed the service.

Some services will need the authentication and some not.

Can anyone help me ?

Thank you